# What is the pdf of the received signal in MIMO radar for CRLB?

Tags: radar, mimo, probability-distribution-function

I studied a [conference paper, *High Resolution Capabilities of MIMO Radar*](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/4176505) and confused about its formula (3).
[image: Pdf of the received signal vector given a scatterer at X with reflectivity a]

As mentioned in paper that the noise $n_{k,l}(t)$ in the received signal $r_{k,l}(t)$ ($r_{k,l}(t) = as_k(t-\tau_{k,l}(X))+n_{k,l}(t)$) is white Gaussian noise, so for the pdf, I think it should follow the Gaussian/Normal distribution form. However, the equation has an integral on the pdf which makes it to cdf not pdf. And this make me confused.
I once think that the integral is used because of multile antennas ($k$ and $l$) but according to the book *Fundamentals of Statistical Signal Processing*, the situation of multiple observations is only sums the pdf together, not use the integral.
[image: Fundamentals of Statistical Signal Processing,Chapter 3, Example 3.3]